# Migrate from aws rds aurora(postgres engine) to regular rds postgres

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds, restore, database-restore

Due to high i/o cost we want to migrate from aurora(Postgres engine) to Postgres. Is there any way to do this.
If no is rebuilding the entire dataset is the only option?

Comment: You can use DMS: https://aws.amazon.com/dms/

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of options you can look into for this migration:

- Use AWS Database Migration Service to use Aurora PostgreSQL as source, and Postgres(RDS or any other) as target. Refer to the documentation to check on version support and configurations.
  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.PostgreSQL.html#CHAP_Source.PostgreSQL.RDSPostgreSQL
- Test setting up logical replication from Aurora PostgreSQL to move data changes.
  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraPostgreSQL.Replication.Logical.html

If the above options are unsuccessful, you can try to re-build with a native dump and restore which could be a more time taking process.